# Nifi EvaluateXPATH Processor not returning node value

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-nifi

Hi I am trying to extract value of "sid" from below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<sid>1245.108628_C5B4C815-9DF7-4246-AB02-9F72191B70E9</sid>
</response>
```

I am using below configuration. But the response is full XML content in text format.
Please help me crack this. I have spent several hours on net trying to figure out this seemingly simple problem.

[EvaluateXPATHProcessor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDT5f.png)

What should be my search string so that it returns only the value of SID in text format?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What about `/response/sid/text()` or `//sid/text()` or `//*[local-name()="sid"]/text()` ?

Comment: @E.Wiest From my understanding, nifi's xpath support is iffi (that's supposed to be a joke...); so it may be the case that every one of your suggestions may have to be wrapped with `string()` as well (after dropping the `text()` part)!

Comment: Thanks @E.Wiest for the suggestion. I have tried all of these options previously. And my o/p is always the full XML :                                                                           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <sid>1594812191.91658_21DCFBF3-23F5-4727-AABC-61159E847817</sid>
</response>

Comment: Thanks @Jack Fleeting. Tried wrapping various search options in string(). But same response. Not able to point out what the issue is. Documentation on Nifi official is very basic.

Comment: What's the output if you turn off `DTD` validation and specify `string` (as suggested by Jack) for the `return type` ? Something like : `Type Destination: flowfile-content; Return Type: string; Validate DTD: false; SID : //sid`

Comment: Hi All, it worked fine with following configurations. Thanks for your time and suggestions!   Destination >> Flowfile-Content. Return type >>String. Validate DTD >> True. SID>>//sid.